Usage of Pluck function in the dataweave
Tring the below dataweave but its not able to achieve using pluck. Please help :
Input:
{
"EmpoyeeID" : "123" ,
"employee_salary_in_last3_months" :  1000 ,
"employee_salary_in_last6_months": 1750,
"employee_salary_in_last12months" : 3000,
}
Output:
{
"EmpoyeeID": "123",
"Salary":
{
"Amounts": [
{
"Duration": "3 months",
"Salary": "1000"
},
{
"Duration": "6 months",
"Salary": "1750"
},
{
"Duration": "12 months",
"Salary": "3000"
}
]
}
}
Tried the below function :
%dw 2.0
output application/json
---
{
"EmpoyeeID" : payload.EmpoyeeID,
"Salary": {
      "Amounts": payload pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
      
      "Duration" : value.employee_salary_in_last3_months
      
      )

}

}


You input JSON is invalid. It has an extra comma at the end.

You are using incorrectly pluck(). It returns an array of each key-pair in the input object. key is the actual key and value the actual value. For example for employee_salary_in_last3_months" : 1000 then key is employee_salary_in_last3_months (of type Key) and value is 1000. So it makes no sense to use a key selector on this value.
Also pluck() will return records for all key-pairs, not just the salary related ones. You can use filterObject() to remove key EmpoyeeID (should it be EmployeeID?). Additionally you need to extract the number of months from the key name. I used a couple of replace...with.
%dw 2.0
output application/json  
---
{
  "EmpoyeeID": payload.EmpoyeeID,
  "Salary": {
        "Amounts": 
            payload 
                filterObject ((value, key) -> key as String startsWith  "employee_salary_in_last")
                pluck ((value, key) -> 
                    {
                        "Duration": (key as String) replace "employee_salary_in_last" with "" replace "_" with "" replace "months" with " months",
                        Salary: value
                    }
    )
  }
}

Input (fixed):
{ 
    "EmpoyeeID" : "123",
    "employee_salary_in_last3_months" : 1000,
    "employee_salary_in_last6_months": 1750,
    "employee_salary_in_last12months" : 3000 
}

Output:
{
  "EmpoyeeID": "123",
  "Salary": {
    "Amounts": [
      {
        "Duration": "3 months",
        "Salary": 1000
      },
      {
        "Duration": "6 months",
        "Salary": 1750
      },
      {
        "Duration": "12 months",
        "Salary": 3000
      }
    ]
  }
}


Thank to so much for providing this solution. It worked like a  charm.

%dw 2.0
import * from dw::core::Arrays 
output application/json skipNullOn = "everywhere"
---

{ 

"EmployeeID" : payload.EmployeeID,
"Salary" : {
    "Amounts" : (payload - "EmployeeID") pluck ((value, key, index) -> 
    {

    "Duration" : if((key splitBy  "_")[-1] == "months")
                ((key splitBy  "_")[-2])[-1] ++ " " ++ (key splitBy  "_")[-1]                else
                null     
     ,

    "Salary" : value
    
    })
    
     
}
}


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
